# relation between the coordinates of the vector on the unit sphere

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, spheres

Let $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a vector on $S^{n-1}$. Reorder coordinates such that $|x_1|\leq \ldots \leq |x_n|$.

I am wondering if there is a some relation between the absolute value of the coordinates of the vector $x$?

For example, to have all non-zero coordinates, I should have that, say, all of the coordinates would be $1/\sqrt n$. What happened if vector would have $k$ non-zero coordinates--would  be the upper bound for $x_i$?

Thank you.

Comment: But, $1/\sqrt n$ is not a lower or upper bound, its just the quadratic mean of the absolute values of the coordinates. $|x_1|\le 1/\sqrt n\le |x_n|$ is we can state.

Comment: @Berci: I did not get, why $|x_1|\leq 1/\sqrt n$?

Comment: We know $|x_1|\leq 1/\sqrt n$ because if not they would all be greater than $1/\sqrt n$ and the sum of squares would exceed $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if all the coordinates are non-zero, one could be almost $1$ and the rest could be very small.  You can say that at least one coordinate is at least $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ in absolute value, but that is about it.

Comment: (+1): We can also say that at least one coordinate is at most $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ in absolute value.

Comment: @CameronBuie:  correct you are.  Thanks.